# Unable to add `linkerd.io/inject: enabled` to ArgoCD manifest - invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.annotations

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, argocd, argoproj

I can install bitnami/redis with this helm command:

```
helm upgrade --install "my-release" bitnami/redis \
     --set auth.existingSecret=redis-key \
     --set metrics.enabled=true \
     --set metrics.podAnnotations.release=prom \
     --set master.podAnnotations."linkerd\.io/inject"=enabled \
     --set replica.podAnnotations."linkerd\.io/inject"=enabled
```

Now I want to install it using [ArgoCD Manifest](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/declarative-setup/).

```
project: default
source:
  repoURL: 'https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami'
  targetRevision: 14.1.1
  helm:
    valueFiles:
      - values.yaml
    parameters:
      - name: metrics.enabled
        value: 'true'
      - name: metrics.podAnnotations.release
        value: 'prom'
      - name: master.podAnnotations.linkerd.io/inject
        value: enabled
      - name: replica.podAnnotations.linkerd.io/inject
        value: enabled
      - name: auth.existingSecret
        value: redis-key
  chart: redis
destination:
  server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  namespace: default
syncPolicy: {}
```

But I'm getting validation error because of `master.podAnnotations.linkerd.io/inject` and `replica.podAnnotations.linkerd.io/inject`

```
error validating data: ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.template.metadata.annotations."linkerd): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.annotations: got "map", expected "string"

error validating data: ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec.template.metadata.annotations."linkerd): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta.annotations: got "map", expected "string"
```

If I remove these two annotation settings the app can be installed.
I've tried `master.podAnnotations."linkerd.io\/inject"`, but it doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with the "." or "/". Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this example](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/application.yaml), parameters containing dots need to be escaped.